# Сколько вопросов в день может задать один участник?

Tags: обсуждение

**Нужно ли ограничивать количество вопросов или связывать это количество с рейтингом участника?**

Что если этих вопросов будет десять, двадцать или еще больше за один день? Чисто технически за таким количеством просто не видно вопросов других людей.

Раньше такой проблемы не было, но вот теперь появилась.

**И о самих вопросах.** Вопросы  участника prostorech кажутся мне  странными, как будто они  набраны из разных источников. Причина такой "любознательности" тоже не очень ясна.

На нашем форуме, как мне кажется, мы помогаем решать те проблемы, которые важны для человека, но которые он не может решить сам.

Если это этимология, то он может  предварительно посмотреть информацию в Интернете, в общеизвестных словарях. Также вопросы, связанные с исторической грамматикой и фонетикой, которые, **возможно, еще не решены даже специалистами**,  могут оказаться сложными для участников форума.

В любом случае хотелось бы видеть заинтересованность участника в их решении и его собственные мысли по заданным темам, иначе просто трудно отвечать на вопросы.

Comment: А почему вопросы про истграм не являются профильными? [«Мы приветствуем вопросы, связанные с различными разделами языкознания (будь то орфография или пунктуация, синтаксис или грамматика, этимология или лексика), о его __истории__ и современном состоянии».](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Некоторые вопросы требуют, вероятно, очень глубоких знаний, которыми обладают специалисты, постоянно работающие в этой области. На других лингвистических форумах их отнесли бы в специальный раздел. Впрочем, по данной проблеме это не самый существенный вопрос.  А существенно то, что остальные вопросы отодвигаются на второй план и их трудно найти. К примеру на сайте "Большой вопрос" есть количественные ограничения: например, не больше двух вопросов день, если у вас невысокий рейтинг.

Comment: @Sharon поддерживаю. Вопросы участника prostorech больше похожи на спам, их количество и однообразность лично меня раздражают. Ощущение, что prostorech просто копирует из какой-то базы, не пытаясь найти решение. Уже событие, когда в ленте нахожу вопрос другого участника. Если надо будет проголосовать за ограничение, обязательно присоединюсь.

Comment: Я ограничение тоже поддержу. В принципе этимологические вопросы могут быть интересными, если  у них есть связь с современной живой речью, но, конечно, не в таком количестве. Отвечать на них сложно еще и потому, что мы не видим, в чем личный интерес prostorech: что он уже знает, а что ему узнать не удалось, почему нужна наша помощь. Поэтому нет эмоциональной заинтересованности. Практически все вопросы требуют хорошего знания исторической грамматики, старославянского языка, поэтому они не всем доступны и интересны. Такие вопросы подошли бы для специального форума

Comment: STACK EXCHANGE включает большое количество сообществ, например сообщество "Лингвистика"  Это вопросы и ответы для профессиональных лингвистов и всех заинтересованных в лингвистических исследованиях и теории. Математика обсуждается в нескольких сообществах (сам предмет, его история, его преподавание и т.д.). Почему бы не организовать группы "Старославянский язык", "Историческая грамматика русского языка" и т.д. в разделе "Лингвистика", например.

Comment: @Sharon ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с https://rus.stackexchange.com/tour. «Русский язык» — это сайт вопросов и ответов для __лингвистов__ и энтузиастов русского языка. Почему вы считаете наш сайт недостаточно «специальным»?

Comment: Я считаю так по фактам.  Большая часть вопросов посвящены современной грамотной речи, это самые актуальные вопросы всех пользователей языка. Среди постоянно отвечающих у нас энтузиастов больше, чем лингвистов, и они прекрасно справляются с такой задачей, не хуже профессионалов. Именно поэтому у нас хорошая  посещаемость и большой интерес к нашему форуму.  А большое количество чисто лингвистических вопросов просто отпугнет посетителей.Есть еще один сайт "Русский  язык" Вопросы и ответы для студентов, преподавателей и лингвистов, желающих обсудить тонкости русского языка.

Comment: Есть сайт "Лингвистика" - Вопросы и ответы для профессиональных лингвистов и других, заинтересованных в лингвистических исследованиях и теории. Поэтому старославянский язык, историческую грамматику и фонетику лучше все-таки обсуждать там, специалистам эти вопросы, наверное, будут интересны. Надо развивать свои СИЛЬНЫЕ стороны - это одинаково относится как к людям, так и к сообществам.

Comment: @Sharon 1) Российская экономика — не сильная сторона страны; по вашей логике ее развивать не стоит? 2) На Linguistics писать можно только по-английски и вопросы о старославянском не могут нести частный характер: как правило, нужно показать, чем та или иная сторона языка полезна для общей лингвистической теории.

Comment: @Aer, вот к чему эта демагогия насчет "российской экономики"? Вы не видите, что девять из десяти вопросов нашего обсуждаемого участника - откровенная задорновщина и чудиновщина? И с любого серьезного сайта его выгнали бы в шесть секунд. Что, скорее всего, и происходит регулярно. Надеюсь, не сочтете за "оскорбление"... А это надо видеть, вы же модератор. Или я чего-то не понимаю, и ваша цель - любой ценой привлечь на сайт любых людей с любыми вопросами?

Comment: @Niemand если вы считаете, что вопросы нарушают правила, помечайте их тревогой. На мой взгляд, вы ошибаетесь в своих представлениях и используете неверный тон, чтобы донести свое мнение до других участников.

Comment: @Aer Что толку-то помечать? Помечаю, минусую. И другие участники, причем такие, что не мне чета, высказываются практически однозначно. Повторяю: на любом серьезном сайте за пяток подобных вопросов говорят давайдосвиданья - и с волчьим билетом. Вы хотите превратить сайт в помойку? У вас неплохо получается. Извините если что не так.

Comment: @Niemand толк есть — другие участники путем голосования решают, оставлять вопрос на сайте или нет.

Comment: @Aer Сами знаете, народ у нас терпеливый - не многие голосуют против. Вот против меня тоже голосуют очень немногие, но у вас же есть власть регулярно меня банить? Ладно, бывает, что за дело, хотя и редко. Здесь же сайт превращен в реальную помойку, но вы ждете, когда публика, совсем уже осатанев, сама будет закрывать вопросы. Где у вас логика-то?

Comment: Кстати, нельзя ли наконец исправить это чудовищное "Мы обращаемся к вам по поводу вашей учетной записи"? Это есть по-русски?

Comment: @Niemand вы пытаетесь добиться от меня пламенной реакции, выкриков о некой «помойке», хотите пожаловаться на несправедливую модерацию или просто обвинить в отсутствии «логики»? Спешу вас заверить, что на нашем сайте уместно только одно: если вы считаете, что против вас несправедливо применены санкции, напишите администрации сайта («Свяжитесь с нами»).

Comment: @Niemand создайте, пожалуйста, отдельный вопрос здесь, на Мете. Если предложите там вариант получше, будет прекрасно!

Comment: @Aer, нет, это я кричу о помойке, а от вас пытаюсь добиться *действий*, а не выкриков. Речь не обо мне, это так, к слову пришлось. К тому, что права-то у вас есть, пора бы и власть употребить.

Comment: А "отдельного вопроса" такая мелочь не стоит. Хотя бы "мы обращаемся к вам по поводу вашего *поведения*". А не учетной записи. Скромненько и со вкусом.

Comment: *>> А большое количество чисто лингвистических вопросов просто отпугнет посетителей.Есть еще один сайт "Русский язык" Вопросы и ответы для студентов, преподавателей и лингвистов, желающих обсудить тонкости русского языка* @Sharon, дело в том, что за такие вопросы с серьезных сайтов выгоняют в два счета. ) Ну, за девять из десяти уж точно. Задорновщина и чудиновщина. Поэтому такие люди и идут сюда - здесь все можно.

Comment: @Niemand, Не могу сказать по поводу вопросов (как их встретят на других сайтах), мне они кажутся достаточно вменяемыми. Я думаю,   что они были бы интересными для специалистов узкого профиля. Просто так сложилось, что тематика нашего сайта - это современная грамотная русская речь, что важно для каждого человека. Это наша сильная сторона, наше преимущество. Этимологию мы тоже обсуждаем, но чаще  на общеобразовательном (доступном для каждого носителя языка) уровне. А как решить проблему технически - я не знаю. Поэтому пока просто пропускаю эти вопросы и ищу нашу привычную тематику.

Comment: @Sharon не забывайте, что вы можете добавить определенные метки, например _этимология_ или _историческая грамматика_, в игнорируемые, и они будут скрываться.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я об этом не знала. Наверное, я так и сделаю.

Answer (score 4):

На сайте уже есть встроенный механизим, ограничивающий количество плохих вопросов от участника.

Если существующие вопросы участника имеют общий рейтинг ниже определенного порога - [сработает question ban](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149). Если участник часто удаляет свои вопросы, однотипно спамит - сработает question ban. По опыту сайта Stack Overflow на Русском - работает практически безотказно.

Для срабатывания нужны голоса "против" тех вопросов, которые вы считаете неуместными. Минусование на вопросах бесплатно. Но при этом стоит оценивать вопрос, а не его автора (и не частоту вопросов от автора).

Не стоит дополнительно ограничивать добросовестных новичков только потому, что они задали несколько простых вопросов подряд.

---

*Нескольких десятков* вопросов подряд - несколько иная ситуация. Пост 40 вопросов в день, скорее всего, является обычным спамом "вопросы ради вопросов".

Правила сайта требуют, чтобы вопросы были основаны на реальных проблемах.

> Следует задавать исключительно практические вопросы, основанные на реальных проблемах, на которые можно дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Даже если спам-вопросы формально соответствуют правилам - они все равно наносят ущерб. За ними теряются вопросы от других участников, которые действительно хотят получить решение. Сообщество существует ради того, чтобы помогать людям находить ответы. А не ради сборки всех возможных вопросов по русскому языку в одной большой таблице в базе данных где-то на диске безымянного сервера.

Не думаю, что стоит вводить дополнительное жесткое ограничение в правилах ради одного случая. Текущих требований к вопросам вполне достаточно для того, чтобы прекратить спам в случае, если он создает реальную проблему для других участников.

Answer (score 3):

Если вопросы интересные и не нарушают правила, то зачем же вводить на них ограничение? Если пользователь будет создавать много вопросов, которые будут закрываться, а также иметь низкий рейтинг, то система сама введет ограничения.

Нельзя сказать, что вопросы одного человека более важные, чем вопросы другого; это просто неправильно. Поэтому все имеют право задать вопрос, который будет отображаться на главной странице.

Если вы считаете, что какой-то вопрос не имеет решения, то стоит дать соответствующий обоснованный ответ. «Слишком сложный вопрос» — понятие, не рассматриваемое правилами сети Stack Exchange.

Comment: А как Вы думаете, почему на эти интересные вопросы  мало ответов, может быть, они не вызывают у людей интерес. Если, к примеру, я сейчас возьму словарь Шанского и буду из него задавать каждый день по 10-15 вопросов. Какая будет реакция у участников форума и, главное,  у системы? Допустим, у них будет низкий рейтинг, но кто их закроет? Повтор вопроса? Но там много очень простых слов, о которых еще никто не спрашивал. Интересный вопрос должен иметь интригу и какую-то историю: почему его задали, что в нем трудного и нерешенного, тогда люди будут отвечать.

Comment: @Sharon я не могу отвечать за других, но мне пара вопросов понравились. Про реакцию также не могу ничего сказать. Закрывать вопросы можно голосованием (сначала — нажмите на кнопку _тревога_ и т. д.). Этот механизм вполне успешно функционирует.

Comment: Мы уже сказали, что бы мы хотели. Введите разумное ограничение (например, не больше 5 вопросов в день для всех, все равно никто столько не задает). Установите дополнительное требование к качеству вопроса: что вам показалось трудным, когда вы хотели решить этот вопрос самостоятельно или что-нибудь в этом роде.  Я не понимаю. почему нельзя сначала заглянуть в словарь, а уж потом спрашивать.

Comment: @Sharon чем диктуется необходимость в таком ограничении? Я не в силах установить что-либо самостоятельно, ввести какое-либо новое правило. Для этого нужно, чтобы большая часть сообщества приняла участие в обсуждении и пришла к более или менее единому мнению.

Comment: Просто на три страницы вопросы от одного человека (и почти все без ответа), трудно ориентироваться в других вопросах.

Comment: С каким обоснованием можно закрывать такие вопросы? Ни одна из имеющихся причин для закрытия не подходит, формально вопросы удовлетворяют всем правилам. А неформально prostorech несколько часов назад прошелся по всем своим вопросам, изменил их одинаковым образом (убрал вопрос про "однокоренные?") из заголовка, и теперь первые страницы опять захламлены.

Comment: @Сибиряк если причин для закрытия нет (т. е. правила не нарушены), вопрос не может быть закрыт. Мы разберемся в происшедшем, спасибо.

Comment: >> *@Aer: я не могу отвечать за других, но мне пара вопросов понравились* -- Из скольких?!  Вот каким вы представляете себе человека, задающего каждый день по пачке подобных "вопросов"? Он студент филфака? Любознательный школьник? Слесарь, в свободное время увлекающийся старославянским? Ну надо же хоть немного разбираться в людях, господа модераторы...

Был тут некогда такой Федя Избушкин - очень похож.

Comment: >>  *@Sharon: Введите разумное ограничение (например, не больше 5 вопросов в день для всех, все равно никто столько не задает)* Не больше двух.

Comment: @Niemand уберите, пожалуйста, оскорбления/изобличения. Вопросы задавать можно и нужно, главное, хорошо их оформлять и формулировать. Это правило распространяется на всех участников. Кстати, на хорошем филфаке студент сам знает ответы на вопросы in question.

Comment: @Aer Где вы видите оскорбления?! Вы по существу-то можете ответить? Каким вы представляете себе человека, задающего каждый день по пачке подобных "вопросов"?

Comment: @Niemand убрал сам, а на вопросы ответить можем, вы главное вопрос задайте, пожалуйста :)

Comment: +1 один голос за ограничение не больше 5 вопросов от человека в день. Представить себе вменяемого человека, которому требуется задать 40 однотипных вопросов за пару дней и продолжать ещё и ещё, не могу. Один, два, четыре — бывает. Но это же нелепо, что один участник превратил целый форум в свалку

Comment: Упрёки в сторону prostorech считаю беспочвенными. Во-первых, и без его вопросов полно таких, которые решаются простым открытием словаря. Во-вторых, его вопросы зачастую с какой-то подковыркой. Лично мне они кажутся занятными.

Answer (score 2):

Моё мнение.

Любой форум должен был бы порадоваться такому количеству вопросов (учитывая их средний уровень). Некоторые вопросы, которые я разбирал, поначалу казались надуманными и искусственными, но в итоге привели к интересному расследованию. Очевидно, что участник prostorech — не профессионал, но он и не претендует на отстаивание некоторых своих заблуждений, как это делают "фрики" и, возможно, "тролли".

> В любом случае хотелось бы видеть заинтересованность участника в их
>   решении и его собственные мысли по заданным темам, иначе просто трудно
>   отвечать на вопросы.

Вот с этим я полностью соглашусь. Нежелание раскрывать свои вопросы чуть подробнее и отсутствие "обратной связи" по ответам демотивирует. Но к этому можно относиться с пониманием — все люди разные и они вправе вести себя в дозволенных рамках. Другое дело, что prostorech сам в первую очередь от этого теряет, но если его всё устраивает, то и пусть.

Comment: Вопрос задан, но проблема не определена. Как тут отвечать? Может быть prostorech сам знает ответ или половину ответа? Может у него, есть версия, но нет уверенности в ее правильности? Или не хватает источника, чтобы подтвердить свои выводы?То есть неясен путь, который уже пройден, как будто намеренно скрыт. А это не располагает к искренности и сотрудничеству. И уровень его знаний сложно определить: с одной стороны, не Шанского же ему пересказывать, с другой - на какой уровень ответов он может рассчитывать на форуме, который не специализирован на темы   по истории языка?

Comment: @Sharon Согласен по всем пунктам.

Answer (score 2):

Как писал PashaPash, [система сама ограничивает возможность задавать вопросы при необходимости](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/6). Это происходит, когда участник задает вопросы низкого качества в большом количестве. Какие вопросы являются низкого качества, решает сообщество голосуя «за» или «против». Таким образом, на мой взгляд, вводить дополнительные ограничения смысла не имеет. Задаваемые вопросы либо соответствуют правилам сайта (интересные, полезные людям, тематичные, заданы по правилам и т.д.), либо низкого качества. Если вопросы как–либо не соответствуют сайту, просто голосуйте против, за закрытие и удаление. Далее система сама сама решит, наложить на участника ограничения или выдать дополнительные [привилегии](/help/privileges).

Сайты Stack Exchange созданы не только для помощи человеку здесь и сейчас, но и для накопления знаний. Основная идея позади в том, чтобы в 99% случаев интересующий человека вопрос уже был на сайте. Это позволяет сэкономить много времени. Таким образом, ограничивать количество вопросов лишь потому, что автор задает много вопросов (с условием, что их качество соответствует сайту), на мой взгляд, не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Мое мнение:

Нужно **срочно** ограничить количество вопросов в день для одного участника.

На этом сайте не должно быть разделения на профильные и непрофильные вопросы. Можете дать ответ — отвечайте, не можете — оставьте вопрос без ответа. Ничего страшного в этом не вижу.

Если вопрос не тривиальный (типа "как писать жи и ши") и не из серии д/з и т. п., то вы не вправе требовать от участника провести дополнительную работу над темой и изложить собственные мысли.

Comment: Формально - да, мы не делим вопросы, но две проблемы требуют решения. Во-первых, как бы эти вопросы ограничить или сложить в отдельную папку и  вывести из общего списка, чтобы можно было нормально работать с другими вопросами. А там пусть отвечает, кто хочет. Во-вторых, о качестве вопросов. Мы должны видеть, что требуется помощь в решении вопроса, с которым автор не может справиться сам. Тогда требуется доработка к требованиям, изложенным в правилах. Может, как-то к модераторам обратиться?

Comment: Я надеюсь, модераторы читают все вопросы на  Мете.  А прямой путь — используйте "тревогу".

Comment: Может быть, Вы, как редактор сайта?

Comment: Вопросы помечены меткой "этимология". Я не вижу другой возможности отделить их от других вопросов.

Comment: ?! Я и не знал, что меня произвели в редакторы. Спасибо, что подсказали. Надо бы узнать, какие права это мне дает. Хорошо, я пошлю "тревогу" модератору.

Comment: Значит, надо найти такую техническую возможность. Если, к примеру,  у автора больше десяти вопросов без ответов и голосов, то надо (для всех таких авторов) выделить специальную папку. Есть же у нас папки с пометками "конкурсные" и др.

Comment: Sharon, редакторы — это все те, кто что-то редактировал на сайте, Вы и себя среди них найдете, у Вас 9 правок.

Comment: Ну вот, а я думала, что это называется правкой, а не редактированием.

Comment: Плохой перевод с английского.