# Теперь у нашего сайта есть блог — пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с ним!

Tags: обсуждение, новости, выход-из-беты, блог

### Здpавствуйте, друзья!

Этой записью я хотел бы начать **новостной блог** о нашем сайте. Буду рад, если вы поддержите мою идею и будете принимать участие в обсуждении различных событий.

Что ж, начнём!

[image: экспериментальное любительское изображение, созданное мной (с использованием бесплатных шрифтов и шаблонов)]

Первое, что хочется сообщить, это новость об **улучшении статистики сайта**. Если вспомнить, в чём основные причины того, что наш сайт до сих пор [находится в Бете](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/178412) (то есть в промежуточной стадии), лишён специального дизайна (а значит, и возможности дарить активным участникам красивые брендированные сувениры!) и не может себе позволить устроить демократические [выборы модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1984/232295), то среди пришедших на ум параметров будут:

- число новых вопросов в день меньше 10;
- слабая активность на Мете.

Мы долго не могли приблизиться к лучшему положению дел, однако в последнее время — особенно за последний месяц — статистика изменилась:

[image: Статистика нашего сайта]

Порог в десять вопросов за день пройден! Осталось удержать этот результат на несколько месяцев, и нашему сайту уделят внимание и почти наверняка сделают полноценным — таким, как, например, сайт об [английском языке](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

---

Кстати, о Мете. Недавно было задано несколько вопросов о том, как устроен сайт. Например, [«Сколько вопросов в день может задать один участник?»](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) — поводом послужило внезапно возросшее количество вопросов про историю языка. Хочется сказать спасибо всем участникам, обратившим внимание на обсуждение, ведь подобные события как ничто иное свидетельствуют о том, что **сайт живёт и развивается**.

---

В завершение первого (пробного) выпуска блога отмечу, что совсем скоро сайт «Русский язык» ждёт **кое-что новое**. Нет, это не собственный дизайн или что-то напрямую связанное с выходом из Беты; однако, надеюсь, грядущее событие значительно поспособствует продвижению сайта и улучшению атмосферы на нём.

---

На этом всё!

Пожалуйста, оставьте ответ или комментарий со своим мнением о формате — **стоит ли продолжать или нет**? И, конечно, приветствуются любые обсуждения по теме выпуска :)
[image: А это точка. Чтобы было красиво.]

Answer (score 2):

Количество вопросов по истории языка возросло, это должно порадовать любителей истории языка. **Жаль только не возросло количество вопросов по современному языку.** Может быть, есть какие-нибудь методы для увеличения таких вопросов?

К примеру, хотелось бы **расширить тематику форума.** У нас совсем не обсуждаются вопросы о художественных особенностях текста.  О том, какие  приемы используют писатели, что нового в их творческих лабораториях. Можно обсудить информационный стиль: где его стоит применять, а где нет.

Сейчас текстовый анализ изучается даже в младших классах. Это не анализ содержания художественной литературы, а анализ именно языковой формы: грамматической структуры, лексики и т.д.

Были бы интересны вопросы **по школьной тематике**, олимпиадные вопросы.

И ещё: есть ли какие-нибудь **технические приемы,** позволяющие **рекламировать** сайт, чтобы привлечь новых посетителей, расширить тематику обсуждаемых вопросов.

Comment: Увы, увеличение количества вопросов по любой тематике напрямую связано с количеством и активностью людей, посещающих сайт. Если увеличатся последние параметры, то, я уверен, появится и больше вопросов на упомянутые вами темы. Про расширение тематики: кажется, у нас и не запрещены вопросы по авторскому стилю! Видимо, их просто не задают :( Может быть, имеет смысл начать самостоятельно задавать подобные вопросы, и тогда «подтянутся» другие? | Технически — да: делиться ссылкой на сайт со знакомыми, в соцсетях и т. п. Жаль, но у нас нет рекламного бюджета, чтобы организовывать рекламные кампании.

Comment: А есть ли у вас мнение насчет такого формата блогов? Стоит ли продолжать?

Comment: Мне нравится, что можно быстро связаться с Вами и задать интересующий вопрос. Поэтому я поддерживаю идею блога.  Мне кажется, что есть какие-то технические приемы для увеличения посещаемости, блогеры, наверное, знают. Может быть, на других форумах чаще давать ссылки на сайт и тому подобное. Мне кажется, что о нас мало знают. Если набрать в поисковике "лучшие форумы по русскому языку", то наш сайт там вряд ли укажут.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! | Да, вот поэтому надо чаще делиться ссылками на наш сайт и говорить, что на нем можно задавать любые вопросы о русском языке и давать на них ответы.

Comment: Но, возможно, мы даже сможем организовать создание групп в соцсетях. Нужно об этом серьезно подумать.

Comment: Да, это было бы неплохо. Интересно, "наш блогер" Василий Ефименко не мог бы что-нибудь интересное подсказать. Он очень неравнодушен к русскому языку.

Comment: Давайте попробуем привлечь внимание Василия!

Comment: Если в Google ввести "форум по русскому языку", наш сайт на 4-м месте в результатах поиска. При этом по числу вопросов, поступающих ежедневно, мы абсолютные лидеры. Так что, @Sharon, ваши предположения не соответствуют действительности. Также наш форум имеет самый удобный и современный интерфейс, что огромный плюс.

Comment: Привлечение людей на сайт через группы в соцсетях мне представляется проблематичным. Группы также нужно продвигать. Продвижение по большей части платное. Бесплатный способ — рассылка приглашений на вступление в группу. Но у меня, например, нет друзей в соцсетях, которые интересуются русским языком. Можно рассылать приглашения по участникам групп, схожих по тематике. Но большинство групп о русском языке имеют развлекательный характер, их участники не ищут ответы на вопросы и не имеют образовательных целей.

Comment: Наш сайт прекрасно рекламирует себя сам: вбейте любой распространённый вопрос по русскому языку в поисковик, например "наконец запятая", — вопрос с нашего сайта в числе первых результатов. Кстати, именно так в своё время наткнулся на сайт я. Так что для всех, кто является целевой аудиторией нашего сайта (кто ищет ответы на вопросы по русскому языку и/или желает на них отвечать), мы на самом видном месте.

Comment: На мой взгляд, такое естественное продвижение нашего форума поисковиками — самый оптимальный вариант в нашем случае. Только нужно следить за тем, чтобы заголовки вопросов максимально соответствовали тому, как люди будут вбивать свои запросы.

Comment: Также нужно как следует модерировать форум, чтобы ответы и комментарии были доброжелательными и корректными, в том числе и на Мете. Постоянно привлекает моё внимание пользователь Niemand своими ответами в стиле "даже пятиклассник знает ответ на ваш вопрос" на основном форуме и едкими издевательствами над Sharon на Мете. Я не раз жаловался на его ответы и комментарии, но реакции не последовало. Такое поведение вредит нашему форуму, так как отбивает желание одних пользователей задавать, а других отвечать на вопросы.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко большое спасибо! Кстати, вроде бы все едкие комментарии удалялись... или не все?

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко Хотел бы дополнить относительно "наш сайт на 4-м месте в результатах поиска". Если Вы осуществляли серфинг в системе гугл, то необходимо учитывать, что перед выдачей результов поисковой движок, на мой взгляд, лезет в журнал посещений вашего браузера, а также, по моему мнению, просматривает список ваших закладок. Для чистоты эксперимента советую "тестировать" поисковые позиции в режиме инкогнито.

Comment: @prostorech Протестировал в браузере, которым не пользуюсь. Там нет ни закладок, ни истории. Мы уже на 3‑м месте:)

Answer (score 0):

Пишу может не в ту графу и не тем, но… блог все стерпит.  1. Позвольте благодарить отвечающих за помощь! Мне тошно знать, что простая благодарность не разрешается. 2. Как это «Голосовать за самый лучший ответ»? Ведь каждый отвечающий что-то интересное да приносит. Позвольте выбирать хоть два лучших ответа. 3. Введите кнопочку: «Ответы получила, всем довольна, вопрос закрыт». Или она уже есть?

Comment: 1. Вы можете проголосовать за и отметить вопрос галочкой — это лучшая благодарность. Комментарий написать можно, но он будет удален, если содержит лишь благодарность. 2. Вы можете отметить все ответы голосом за. 3. Есть — галочка напротив ответа.

Comment: @Белка  Когда я только начинала работать на сайте, у меня была примерно такая же проблема. Я была очень благодарна всем, кто отвечал на мои вопросы, но никак не могла выбрать лучшего, поэтому и не принимала ответы. Все отвечали так хорошо, дополняли друг друга, как я могла обидеть их, выбрав только одного. Когда непринятых ответов накопилось достаточное количество, кто-то из участников сделал мне замечание. Почему это Вы не принимаете ответы? Наши люди так стараются, а Вам ничего не нравится. Откуда у Вас столько высокомерия? Вот такая вспомнилась история.